# cPickle.load() in python consumes a large memory

Tags: python, memory, pickle

I have a large dictionary whose structure looks like:

```
dcPaths = {'id_jola_001': CPath instance}
```

where CPath is a self-defined class:

```
class CPath(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # some attributes
        self.m_dAvgSpeed = 0.0
        ...
        # a list of CNode instance
        self.m_lsNodes = []
```

where m_lsNodes is a list of CNode:

```
class CNode(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # some attributes
        self.m_nLoc = 0

        # a list of Apps
        self.m_lsApps = []
```

Here, m_lsApps is a list of CApp, which is another self-defined class:

```
class CApp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # some attributes
        self.m_nCount= 0
        self.m_nUpPackets = 0
```

I serialize this dictionary by using cPickle:

```
def serialize2File(strFileName, strOutDir, obj):
    if len(obj) != 0:
        strOutFilePath = "%s%s" % (strOutDir, strFileName)
        with open(strOutFilePath, 'w') as hOutFile:
            cPickle.dump(obj, hOutFile, protocol=0)
        return strOutFilePath
    else:
        print("Nothing to serialize!")
```

It works fine and the size of serialized file is about 6.8GB. However, when I try to deserialize this object:

```
def deserializeFromFile(strFilePath):
    obj = 0
    with open(strFilePath) as hFile:
        obj = cPickle.load(hFile)
    return obj
```

I find it consumes more than 90GB memory and takes a long time.

1. why would this happen?
2. Is there any way I could optimize this?

BTW, I'm using python 2.7.6

Comment: how much memory did the process consume before it dumped the data to the pickle?

Comment: It may depend on the way the stored classes are defined, so it will help if you add the code.

Comment: Are you sure it's the deserialization? Serialization is known to take up quite a bit more memory to handle cyclic references.

Comment: 1. Can you tell us: of which type are the most used objects? 2. Could you dump it with the lowest protocol and show/link some smaller chunks? 3. Do you use Python 3? 4. Does the problem still exist if you use pickle?

Comment: @bereal I have added code of stored classes

Comment: @KillianDS Yes, I have print some log before and after calling the deserializeFromFile() function, so I'm sure it is the deserialization which is consuming such large memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try specifying the pickle protocol; fastest is -1 (meaning: latest
protocol, no problem if you are pickling and unpickling with the same Python version).

```
cPickle.dump(obj, file, protocol = -1)
```

***EDIT***:
As said in the comments: `load` detects the protocol itself.

```
cPickle.load(obj, file)
```

Comment: Could I dump with protocol = 0 and load with protocol = -1? Because I have already dumped data with protocol = 0 and the problem now is how could I load it back? Besides, I can't find the protocol parameter in cPickle.load().

Comment: @ice_lin `load` detects the protocol itself, you can only specify it on `dump`/`dumps`. But protocol 0 is not very efficient and might at least partially explain the issues you see.

Comment: @ice_lin: load your data dumped with protocol 0, then re-dump them with protocol = -1...

Answer (score 0):

When you store complex python objects, python usually stores a lot of useless data (look at the `__dict__` object property).

In order to reduce the memory consumption of unserialized data you should pickle only python natives. You can achieve this easily implementing some methods on your classes: `object.__getstate__()` and `object.__setstate__(state)`.

See [Pickling and unpickling normal class instances](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-normal-class-instances) on python documentation.

Comment: That `__dict__` is a standard way of representing python objects, it would be there also before pickling, so it would *not* explain a memory increase.

Comment: @KillianDS but a lot of referenced stuff is serialized as well because is impossible to update references to custom objects to their new counterparts on a new environment.

Pickle does some magic to minimize this effect (resolving types inspecting at module level), but unwanted instances (like singletons) are serialized and duplicated when unpickling.