# Python dictionary loaded from disk takes too much space in memory

Tags: python, file-io, pickle

I have a dictionary pickled on disk with size of ~780 Megs (on disk). However, when I load that dictionary into the memory, its size swells unexpectedly to around 6 gigabytes. Is there anyway to keep the size around the actual filesize in the memory as well, (I mean it will be alright if it takes around 1 gigs in the memory, but 6 gigs is kind of a strange behavior). Is there a problem with the pickle module, or should I save the dictionary in some other format?

Here is how I am loading the file:

```
import pickle

with open('py_dict.pickle', 'rb') as file:
    py_dict = pickle.load(file)
```

Any ideas, help, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May I recommend using `sqlite3` instead of a Python dictionary to store that data?

Comment: This might be relevant: http://www.shocksolution.com/2010/01/storing-large-numpy-arrays-on-disk-python-pickle-vs-hdf5adsf/

Comment: This is a similar question, might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261598/cpickle-load-in-python-consumes-a-large-memory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using `pickle` just for storing large values in a dictionary, or a very large number of keys, you should consider using [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) instead.

```
import shelve
s=shelve.open('shelve.bin')
s['a']='value'
```

This loads each key/value only as needed, keeping the rest on disk

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL to store all the data into a database and use efficient queries to reach it.

Comment: Thanks. This is so helpful. Yes, another alternate is definitely to use a db, but the file (not large right now), will be growing in size, possibly gigs, so I think storing locally is much more feasible.

Comment: If you use SQLite, the database is local - the SW is embedded in python, and it can use a local file for the DB.