# Why does a file stored as a dictionary take up much more space than file

Tags: python

I have a file of size `500MB` if I store each line of that file in a dictionary setup like

```
file = "my_file.csv"
with open(file) as f:
    for l in f:
        delimiter = ','
        line = l.split(delimiter)
        hash_key = delimiter.join(line[:4])
        store_line = delimiter.join(line[4:])
        store_dict[hash_key] = store_line
```

To check my memory, I compared the memory usage of my program by watching `htop`, first with the above, then switching the last line to

```
print(hash_key + ":" + store_line)
```

And that took < 100MB of memory.

the size of my store_dict is approximately `1.5GB` in memory.  I have checked for memory leaks, I can't find any.  Removing this line `store_dict[hash_key] = store_line` results in the program taking < 100MB of memory.  Why does this take up so much memory? Is there anyway to store the lines as a dictionary and not have it take up so much memory?

Comment: "*the size of my store_dict is approximately 1.5GB in memory*" - How did you come to know that? What tool did you use to measure it?

Comment: @Robᵩ tracked total memory of my python program, changing  `store_dict[hash_key] = store_line` to `print(hash_key +":"+store_line)`

Comment: @Robᵩ Using the first line, resulted in my program taking 1.5GB of memory, the second line taking < 100MB of memory.

Comment: When you remove that line `store_dict[hash_key] = store_line`, you don't store anything in the dictionary, so naturally no memory is required for that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660717/python-dictionary-loaded-from-disk-takes-too-much-space-in-memory?rq=1

Comment: @mkrieger1 Right, so I am wondering why a dictionary takes 1.5GB of memory to store a 500MB text file of lines. (Where the key is 1/2 the line and the value that key points to, is the other half of the line) so no additional data is being stored

Comment: Also possible: " if you work with Unicode strings, each Unicode character use 2 or 4 bytes in memory. Whereas on your file, assuming UTF-8 encoding, most of the characters use only 1 byte" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313381/why-does-a-dictionary-use-so-much-ram-in-python?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Reducing memory usage of dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264874/python-reducing-memory-usage-of-dictionary)

Comment: @DavidZemens I am decoding each line before I add it to the dictionary `l.decode('utf-8')` .  Also, for your other suggestion, I am making millions of calls to this dictionary every few minutes, so disk storage isn't really practical. (No, these calls don't have memory leaks, I removed all calls and simply filled the dictionary and nothing else and the memory issue still persists

Comment: BTW you can't have memory leaks in your Python code as you're not doing any memory management yourself. Don't worry about that.

Comment: @jo2083248 you might consider providing a [mcve] of your code. You should also edit your question to include details on *how* you determine the memory usage. Simply saying "I tracked memory usage" isn't adequate.

Comment: Basic question, are you using python 3.6? Under 3.6, "The dict type has been reimplemented to use a more compact representation."

Comment: @jpp I am using 3.6

Comment: @DavidZemens I expanded my example to include what you asked, thanks

Comment: The next question I have: is there repeated data in your dictionary values? Reason I ask is if there is a lot of repeated data, you can factorise and potentially save a lot of space.

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's all unique customer data.  Also, unfortunately, I believe dictionary is my best choice for data structure because I need to perform some data validation and using a dictionary allows for `O(1)` runtime of those after they are built.  So, I guess I am stuck between large memory consumption or longer runtime @jpp

Answer (score 2):

Even if the `store_line` `str`s each took up the same amount of memory as the corresponding piece of text in the file on the disk (which they properly don't, especially if you are using Python 3 where `str`s default to Unicode), the `dict` necessarily takes up way more space than your file. The `dict` does not only contain the bare text, but a lot of Python objects.

Each `dict` key and value is a `str`, which each carries not just text information, but also their own lengths and reference counting used for garbage collection. The `dict` itself also need to store meta data about its items, such as the hash of each key and a pointer to each value.

If you had a few, very long lines in the file, then you should expect the Python representation to have comparable memory consumption. That is, *if* you are sure that the file uses the same encoding as Python...